# how many bytes can stdout have until it flushes

Tags: c, printf, size, buffer, stdout

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char password[1];
    int randomNumber;
    int milicseconds;
    
    
    while(1){
    randomNumber = rand() % 93;
    
    randomNumber = randomNumber + 33;
    password[0] = randomNumber;
    
    milicseconds = rand() % 90;
    milicseconds = milicseconds + 10;
    printf("%c",password[0]);
  // fflush(stdout);
    Sleep(milicseconds);
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thats my code to generate random ascii strings. But now I want to know, whats the size of stdout in bytes until it flushes at the console when buffer fills up. Is it right that stdout holds 4096 bytes buffer size? If thats true, how can i check that in C?

Comment: nah... it depends on your specific system

Comment: So what I wanted to say... without specific system information, your question can't be answered

Comment: i tried to get the size of stdout with the sizeof operator like printf("%d",sizeof(stdout)) and i got the number 4. But that can not be the answer, i guess.

Comment: ive got a 8gb ram , so that means i can hold 8096bytes? so that means, it depens on my ram, which is installed in my pc?

Comment: @Winchester, it depends on your C implementation, possibly your software and OS configuration, and possibly on other action performed by your program.  Additionally, depending on several factors, you might find that `stdout` gets flushed when a newline is written to it, regardless of how much data is buffered.

Comment: ok then... i dont understand how i get the buffer of stdout :(

Comment: What system are you on? A Linux/Posix system?

Comment: It is probably in your best interest to avoid depending on the buffer being flushed at any specific data size.  Instead, flush it explicitly at any point where you want to be sure that any buffered content is flushed.  Other than that, don't worry about when it will be flushed.

Comment: im on windows 10.

Comment: @Winchester what you need it for?

Comment: @Winchester I even know implementation when files are flushed at specific intervals to minimize data losses

Comment: @0___________ i need it for my task. I need to implement a string generator which you can see in my first post with the function fflush(stdout) and in the end of the task, they want to know from me: "
If you manage to find out how big the
Output buffer, i.e. how many bytes does it contain?"

Comment: Settable by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setbuffersize

Comment: thanks, one more question. If i print that on console: printf("%d", stdout); I get "1969702432" somebody know what this number means?

Comment: @stark That C# function "_Sets the height and width of the screen buffer area_", not `stdout`s buffer. You can set `stdout`s buffer with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, WantedBufSize);` (up to `INT_MAX` on Windows). I don't know how to get the current buffert size though, but I'm not sure if that matters for OP:s question.

Comment: @Winchester `printf("%d", stdout);` is invalid. You place a `FILE*` where an `int` should be. `%d` will make `printf` read it as an `int` and you'll possibly have a corrupted stack. Don't.

Comment: @Winchester You want to know `stdout`s buffert size - so, just set it. `int main() { size_t WantedBufSize = something; if(setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, WantedBufSize) == 0) printf("Buffert size is now %zu\n",  WantedBufSize); ...` Note that it must be done before _any_ other output.